# Delete Top 1 Desc is pulling the wrong record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I have 2 tables that I need to delete a top record on.

For both tables I have something along the lines of:

```
delete from [TABLE]
where [LINE] = (select top 1 [LINE]
                from [TABLE]
                where NUMBER= 'XXXXXX'
                order by TIME desc)
```

For 1 I am using a local table, and the other I am making a direct call to a separate server. When I run the inner select of both of them they appear to pull the correct record that I want delete, but when I run the whole delete query 1 works correctly (from what I can see) and the other (the server called one) is pulling the ascended top 1 not the descended top 1.

It is really starting to frustrate me and confuse me that these two almost identical commands are acting in 2 opposite ways.

FYI the TIME is a datetime in both tables, and should be entered in each table at virtually the same time.

Comment: If your source table doesn't have an identity column, you could try inserting the records from `[TABLE]` into a **table variable** with an identity ID, then do the delete based on that ID rather than `TIME`.

Comment: Are there duplicate TIME or LINE values?

Comment: There LINES are autogenerated so no, the TIME will have the same date but different time.

The weird part is when I run the individual inner select as before, it works and pulls the right record. when I run the entire delete query, it pulls the wrong record.

Comment: Maybe you should make sure, because if there happen to be duplicate TIME values the exact LINE might be undefined. Note that SQL allows for undefined behavior, so the results do not *have* to be the same each time.; Also, please post the execution plans you are getting.

Comment: gunna pull a noob move here and ask what execution plans are. And I know for sure the dates are the same, but each TIME is several seconds a part.

ex. (2013-09-17 12:41:59:XX, 2013-09-17 12:42:01:XX, 2013-09-17 12:42:03:XX, etc)

Comment: I can see that you got your solution. If you want to dig deeper on this you can toggle "show actual execution plan" in SSMS. It will give you a graphical idea of what SQL Server did to calculate the query results. It is worth spending some time to make yourself familiar with this.

Comment: If you won't mind tell me the location of the toggle. THe only execution plan option I found was "Display Estimated Execution Plan" under Query.

Comment: Well I used what I found, and it appears to be related to the use of Remote Delete instead of Local Delete, this was very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you go by ID? Something like

```
delete from [TABLE]
where [id] = (select max(id)
                from [TABLE]
                where NUMBER= 'XXXXXX')
```

Comment: That appeared to work, but im also curious to why the max was consistent and the datetime was reversed.

Comment: The time you see might be truncated or rounded somehow. That means there would be ties. It would normally come across the first row inserted in the case of a tie. That would be the earlier one.